SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'service' (errno: 13)
MySQL keep failing on creating table. I read about the error on other resources and nothing helped.
When i ran command -
"docker compose -f ./docker/docker-compose-linux.yaml run --rm php-cli ./bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force"

it gives me an error -

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE service (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, category VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, price DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL, pay_type VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, show_on_index TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL, id_crm INT DEFAULT NULL, priority INT DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':


SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'service' (errno: 13)

doctrine.yaml
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback  if the env var is not set. This allows you
    # to run cache:warmup even if your environment variables are not available
    # yet. You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        filesystem_provider:
            file_system:
                directory: "%kernel.project_dir%/var/cache/%kernel.environment%/doctrine"

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        host: '%env(MYSQL_HOST)%'
        port: '%env(MYSQL_PORT)%'
        dbname: '%env(MYSQL_DATABASE)%'
        user: '%env(MYSQL_USER)%'
        password: '%env(MYSQL_PASSWORD)%'

#        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver:
            cache_provider: filesystem_provider
        query_cache_driver:
            cache_provider: filesystem_provider
        result_cache_driver:
            cache_provider: filesystem_provider
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App

Docker compose file -
version: "3.7"

services:
  #PHP
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-php-fpm:7.4.16
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}

  php-cli:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: php-cli/Dockerfile
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-php-cli:7.4.16
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-php-cli
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}

  #Nginx
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-nginx
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
      - ./nginx/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "${EXTERNAL_HTTP_PORT}:80"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm

  #MySQL
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-mysql
    hostname: mysql.loc
    volumes:
      - ../var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${EXTERNAL_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    env_file:
      - '../.env.local'

  #node
  node-cli:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: node/Dockerfile
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-node-cli
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
    working_dir: /app


I tried to change access for folders where usually dbs stored, but the db stored in docker container, so it doesn't seem to help.
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/database_name
chown -R mysql:mysql /tmp

Entered bash in docker and checked that the mysql works properly and db was created, but still table throws an error.

Errno 13 is a permission error. Do you try to use a Docker volume or mount for the MySQL data or tmp directory? Add your docker compose configuration to the question, please.
Further please use a code block to add your Doctrine config instead of an image.

I tried to change access for folders where usually dbs stored - which concrete commands did you execute? Add those to the question please.

Do try not to post pictures of text based information.
